# scrollspy navigate to different page and back at same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello fellow web enthusiasts, I am hoping you could help me out with a problem.

I am using bootstrap to create a website that uses scrollspy to navigate to parts of the page with the navbar. The only way I could get the URL to not display `"#section-2"` when scrolling to a part of a page was to call my javascript in my `<head>`.

**Now the problem...**

I attempted to add an FAQ section which would be a different page completely, hoping to have it link back to specific part of the original page.

It seems as the FAQ `<a> tag` is not working unless the browser is resized..

That's two bugs with scrollspy already!! Is it normal for bootstrap to experience this many bugs?

http://dnwebdev.com

code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        Day &amp; Night | Responsive Web Design
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" data-offset="125">
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dn navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">


            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar">
          </span>
                <span class="icon-bar">
          </span>
                <span class="icon-bar">
          </span>
            </button>




            <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:#2c3e50;">
          Day 
          <img src="../images/dnlogoc.png" height="35px"/>
          Night
        </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="text-align:center;">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#section-1">
              About Us
            </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section-2">
              What We Do
            </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#section-3">
              Our Process
            </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#section-4">
              Our Work
            </a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a href="#section-5">
              Get in touch
            </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/faq">
              FAQ
             </a>
                </li>



            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container day" style="padding-top:75px;">
        <hr>

        <h2 class="center" id="section-1">
        Web Solutions, LLC
      </h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="text-align:center;">
                <img src="../images/dnlogoc.png" height="200px" class="mainimg">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

                <p>
                    Vestibulum quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <p>
            Vestibulum quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="container day">





        <hr>

        <h3 class="center" id="section-2">
        What We Do
      </h3>

        <hr>


        <div class="row">
            <!-- Boxes de Acoes -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 smallpad">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <div class="image">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker">
                </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h3 class="title">
                  Local Search Engine Optimization
                </h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lobortis nisl, vitae iaculis sapien. Phasellus ultrices gravida massa luctus ornare. Suspendisse blandit quam elit, eu imperdiet neque semper.
                            </p>
                            <div class="more">
                                <a href="#" title="Title Link">
                    Read More 
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right">
                    </i>
                  </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 smallpad">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <div class="image">
                            <i class="fa fa-laptop">
                </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h3 class="title">
                  Mobile Friendly Web Design
                </h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lobortis nisl, vitae iaculis sapien. Phasellus ultrices gravida massa luctus ornare. Suspendisse blandit quam elit, eu imperdiet neque semper.
                            </p>
                            <div class="more">
                                <a href="#" class="hover" title="Title Link">
                    Read More 
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right">
                    </i>
                  </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 smallpad">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <div class="image">
                            <i class="fa fa-mobile">
                </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h3 class="title">
                  Responsive - Mobile Friendly Web Design
                </h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lobortis nisl, vitae iaculis sapien. Phasellus ultrices gravida massa luctus ornare. Suspendisse blandit quam elit, eu imperdiet neque semper.
                            </p>
                            <div class="more">
                                <a href="#" title="Title Link">
                    Read More 
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right">
                    </i>
                  </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Boxes de Acoes -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container night">

        <div class="page-header" style="text-align:center;" id="section-3">
            <h2>
          Our Process
        </h2>

            <h3>

        </h3>

        </div>
        <ul class="timeline">
            <li class="timeline">
                <div class="timeline-badge mybadge">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
            </i>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h4 class="timeline-title">
                Planning
              </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>
                            Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="timeline-inverted">
                <div class="timeline-badge mybadge">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
            </i>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h4 class="timeline-title">
                Content
              </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>
                            Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Suco de cevadiss, é um leite divinis, qui tem lupuliz, matis, aguis e fermentis. Interagi no mé, cursus quis, vehicula ac nisi. Aenean vel dui dui. Nullam leo erat, aliquet quis tempus a, posuere ut mi. Ut scelerisque neque et turpis posuere pulvinar pellentesque nibh ullamcorper. Pharetra in mattis molestie, volutpat elementum justo. Aenean ut ante turpis. Pellentesque laoreet mé vel lectus scelerisque interdum cursus velit auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac mauris lectus, non scelerisque augue. Aenean justo massa.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="timeline">
                <div class="timeline-badge mybadge">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">
            </i>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h4 class="timeline-title">
                Design
              </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>
                            Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="timeline-inverted">
                <div class="timeline-badge mybadge">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench">
            </i>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h4 class="timeline-title">
                Development
              </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>
                            Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="timeline">
                <div class="timeline-badge mybadge">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload">
            </i>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h4 class="timeline-title">
                Test &amp; Launch
              </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>
                            Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container day">

        <hr>
        <h3 class="center" id="section-4">
        Our Work
      </h3>
        <hr>

        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 myimg">

                <img src="../images/after-searok.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                    <footer>
                        <cite title="Source Title">
                Searok Charters
              </cite>
                    </footer>
                </blockquote>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 myimg">

                <img src="../images/after-nicor.jpg" class="img-responsive">

                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                    <footer>
                        <cite title="Source Title">
                Nicor
              </cite>
                    </footer>
                </blockquote>



            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 myimg">

                <img src="../images/after-cmt.jpg" class="img-responsive">

                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                    <footer>
                        <cite title="Source Title">
                Castle Mountain Team
              </cite>
                    </footer>
                </blockquote>


            </div>


            <hr>


        </div>

    </div>
    <hr>


    <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <i class="fa fa-5x fa-arrow-right">
        </i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2 class="center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
            All my our work
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <i class="fa fa-5x fa-arrow-left">
          </i>
        </div>
      </h2>
        </div>


        <footer style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="container night nopad">





                <hr>
                <h3 class="center" id="section-5">
          Let's talk about your project!
        </h3>
                <hr>



                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                    <hr>
                    <h2>

            <a href="tel:4073497036">
              <i class="fa fa-phone">
              </i>
              (407) 349-7036
            </a>
          </h2>
                    <hr>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 nopad" style="text-align:center;">
                    <!-- Place this tag where you want the widget to render. -->
                    <div class="g-page" data-width="200" data-href="//plus.google.com/u/0/106333335696092351517" data-theme="dark" data-rel="publisher">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Place this tag after the last widget tag. -->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function () {
                            var po = document.createElement('script');
                            po.type = 'text/javascript';
                            po.async = true;
                            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
                            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                            s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                        })();
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">



                    <hr>

                    <h2>
            <a href="mailto:rob@dnwebdev.com">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o">
              </i>
              rob@dnwebdev.com
            </a>

          </h2>
                    <hr>

                </div>





                <div id="footer" class="day" style="text-align:center;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            Day &amp; Night Web Solutions, LLC
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </footer>
        <script>
            function close_toggle() {
                if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
                    $('.nav a').on('click', function () {
                        $(".navbar-toggle").click();
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.nav a').off('click');
                }
            }
            close_toggle();




            $(window).resize(close_toggle);




             //function that offsets scoll

            if ($(window).width() <= 768) {

                var offset = 100;
            } else {

                var offset = 115;


            }
            $('.navbar li a').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
                scrollBy(0, -offset);
            });
        </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why the question was voted down, this is a legitimate question.

Comment: Thank you for the markup @user1615903, I am still trying to learn the best practices for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a jQuery function that's forcing each of your menu link to scroll to that section. You need to tell the function to do this for all menu-links except *FAQ* and to redirect if *FAQ* clicked, so you do:

```
//trim the spaces and check if the text of the menu link is not equal to 'FAQ'
if ($.trim($(this).html()) != 'FAQ') {
    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -offset);
} else {
    //if it is, redirect to the page
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

**[Full Screen](http://jsfiddle.net/7t85G/1/embedded/result/)** (*[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t85G/1/)*)

### Edit:

From comment:

> when trying to link back I am using ""; which is throwing off the
>   scrollspy by adding #section-2 to the url.

This is quite a tricky to solve because of the limited functions we can use on page redirection. However, you can do this:

First, remove this function `$('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {` completely, and place this code on top of the other scripts:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click','.navbar li a',function(event) {
          alert($(this).html());
        event.preventDefault();
        if($.trim($(this).html())!='FAQ'){
            $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
            scrollBy(0, -offset);
          }
          else
          {
              window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
          }

      });

   //document.referrer returns the url from which this page has been entered,
   //we will use this to check if we are redirected from FAQs page
   var previous_url = document.referrer;
   if(previous_url=='http://dnwebdev.com/dev/faq/'){
   //if we were redirected from FAQ page, we would have a #section-value in our url
   //hash here fetched that value
   var hash = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);

   //this is the important part, we are gonna trigger that the
   //#section-value passed in url is _clicked_. And so the browser will
   //scroll down to that section
   $('.navbar li a#a-'+hash).trigger('click');
   //once it scrolls down, this deletes the #section-value from url
   history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
   }

});
```

For the above to work, you also need to add an `id` attribute to each of your `<a>` tag such as:

```
<a href="#section-1" id="a-section-1">
<a href="#section-2" id="a-section-2">
```

etc.

A little demonstration on how the `trigger` works: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d4g78/)

Comment: This answer seems to work when linking FAQ, thank you!

There is a slight problem though, when trying to link back I am using "<a href="http://dnwebdev.com/dev/#section-2">" which is throwing off the scrollspy by adding #section-2 to the url.

Comment: @Dnwebdev Try pasting this code: `$(document).ready(function(){
 history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
});` on your main page. It will erase your #value after scrolling.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger the following code deletes the #section-2 out of the URL but it also ignores the scrollspy completely, causing the page to link to the beginning no matter what nav is pressed.

Comment: @Dnwebdev Try the above code and let me know if you still have a problem.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger I added it, the outcome was that it deleted "#section-2" from the url but as a result of that when I link back to a page using "<a href="../#section-2"> then the scrollspy for "#secion-2" is ignored.

Please advise, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Can you alert `previous_url` and check if the value is same as `http://dnwebdev.com/dev/faq/`?

Comment: I took the code from the JSfiddle and the first alert (which I put before the 'if previous' showed "http://dnwebdev.com/dev/faq/" and the second alert when coming back to the /dev/ page showed "what we do" which is not "section-2"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52233/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-dnwebdev)

Answer (score 0):

give id to the first div i.e. like dynaDiv and modify `<a href="/faq"> FAQ </a>` as `<a href="/faq" onclick='addFAQ();'> FAQ </a>` define function as

```
function addFAQ(){
  $("#dynaDiv").load("./faq.html");
}
```